# C# byte array to base10 string

Tags: c#

I need to take a byte array and convert it to a string. I basically need to do the opposite of this:

```
BigInteger.Parse(num).ToByteArray();
```

Comment: Lasse is correct, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have:

```
string num = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
byte[] bytes = BigInteger.Parse(num).ToByteArray();
```

and you want to get from the `byte[] bytes` array back to the string `"1234567890123456789012345678901234567890"`, this is the code that reverses that operation:

```
string numDecoded = new BigInteger(bytes).ToString();
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BbpPky)